# Returning IEnumerable straight from database or using ToListAsync before

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do the controllers work when giving them IEnumerable straight from the database? Which code is more correct and optimal? Let's assume that the database is very slow and there are other operations going on.

This example is very simple so there might not be enough difference in execution times but i am trying to learn the best practices.

## #1

```
public Task<Application[]> Find(Expression<Func<Application, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DatabaseContext.Applications
        .Where(predicate)
        .ToArrayAsync();
}

...

public Task<Application[]> Find(...)
{
    return ApplicationService.Find(...);
}
```

## #2

```
public Task<List<Application>> Find(Expression<Func<Application, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DatabaseContext.Applications
        .Where(predicate)
        .ToListAsync();
}

...

public async Task<IActionResult> Find(...)
{
    var applications = await ApplicationService.Find(...)
    return Ok(applications);
}
```

## #3

```
public IEnumerable<Application> Find(Expression<Func<Application, bool>> predicate)
{
    return DatabaseContext.Applications;
}

...

public IActionResult<IEnumerable<Application>> Find(...)
{
    var applications = ApplicationService.Find(...);
    return Ok(applications);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do the controllers work when giving them IEnumerable straight from the database?

(By `IEnumerable` I assume you mean directly returning an unexecuted `IQueryable` from your `DbContext`)

**They don't and you shouldn't** - this is because an unexecuted `IQueryable` does not represent loaded data - and when it is executed it can only load data from an open database connection - which requires an active and valid `DbContext`.

...so if the `DbContext` is disposed, then the `IQueryable` cannot be executed.

If you create the `DbContext` inside the controller action and render the `IQueryable` in your view or return it in an `ObjectResponse` (for Web API) then it will always fail:

```
public IActionResult GetPeople()
{
    // WARNING: NEVER DO THIS!
    using( MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext( GetConnectionString() ) )
    {
        return this.Ok( db.People.Where( p => p.Name == "John Smith" ) );

        // or:

        return this.View( model: db.People.Where( p => p.Name == "John Smith" ) );
    }
}
```

Remember that `.Ok()` and `this.View()` does not trigger evaluation of the View or send an object-response to the client - instead it causes the Controller action to end first and then pass the data on to the next step in the ASP.NET pipeline (i.e. the view). Remember: views are executed after the controller action is finished.

If you use Dependency Injection to have a ready instance of your `DbContext` in the Controller then the results are less predictable: the `IQueryable` can still be evaluated after the action method returns because the `DbContext` won't be disposed until after the Controller is disposed which is generally *after* the view is rendered, however you still shouldn't do this because your `IQueryable` could still be passed-on to some process that outlives the life of your Controller class which would then cause a failure. You should also avoid it because Views are designed to be rendered quickly and synchronously - having an external database or IO call breaks that design.

(And you shouldn't use Entity Framework entity objects as root ViewModels anyway, but that's another discussion).

You can avoid this habit if you always use the `async` operations on `DbContext` (e.g. `ToListAsync()`, `ToDictionaryAsync`, etc - because those return a `Task<List<T>>` or `TaskDictionary<TKey,TValue>>` respectively - which require an `await` which the compiler will prevent you from doing in a View or Object result by default (you *can* have `await` in views, but it's inadvisable and requires setting some settings somewhere).

In short, always do this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetPeople()
{
    using( MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext( GetConnectionString() ) )
    {
        List<Person> list = await db.People
            .Where( p => p.Name == "John Smith" )
            .ToListAsync();

        // WebAPI:
        return this.Ok( list ); // returning an evaluated list, loaded into memory. (Make sure Lazy Navigation Properties are disabled too)

        // MVC:
        PeopleListViewModel vm = new PeopleListViewModel(); // in MVC always use a custom class for root view-models so you're not accepting nor returning Entity Framework entity types directly
        vm.List = list;

        return this.View( vm );
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly as i hoped. I was just thinking that controller would lock the thread to execute query blocking entire API for few ms(or dont) when i could do it asynchronously. . Anyway doing this myself seems to be the best option. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: I mean I/O operations that are not asynchronous and wont let other operations to complete while waiting for a whole database response.

Comment: @MateuszSurma ASP.NET by default uses a dedicated thread for each request/response (I think ASP.NET Core does too) - so one request won't block another until the entire thread-pool is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are returning a task to be executed by the mvc framework;
2. You are running (asynchronously) a task as soon as you await it, then getting the result and handing it to the mvc framework;
3. You are returning an enumerator to be executed by the mvc framework.

I would go with option #2 because you know exactly when the database query will be executed. Since you are returning a Task and correctly using async and await keywords, the framework will keep as many threads as busy as it can, leveraging the throughput of the application.