# Why does the scaffolding-generated controller convert its DbContext's DbSet property to a List before passing it into a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm following [Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#strongly-typed-models-and-the-model-directive-1), and as part of it, I generated CRUD operations for the model *Movie* through scaffolding.

The Index view has the following line at the top:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>
```

And the controller passes that object by converting `DbSet<MvcMovie.Models.Movie>` of its `DbContext` to a List first:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await _context.Movie.ToListAsync());
}
```

The tutorial confirms this is intended behavior:

> Examine the Index.cshtml view and the Index method in the Movies controller. Notice how the code creates a List object when it calls the View method. The code passes this Movies list from the Index action method to the view:

However, looking at the `DbSet` class, it implements `IEnumerable<TEntity>`, and in this case, `TEntity` is the Movie object. So, why bother converting it to a List?

I tested this by passing `_context.Movie` as-is, and it seems to work perfectly fine.

Is there a reason this is done, then?

Comment: You should expose an specific view element, not your EF model.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Unless I'm mistaken, normally in C#, if a method's parameter is of type `IEnumerable<T>`, that parameter will only be accessible as an `IEnumerable<T>` in that method's scope; regardless of what argument you pass in, provided it implements the interface. Is it not the same here?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57368780/returning-ienumerable-straight-from-database-or-using-tolistasync-before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tested this by passing _context.Movie as-is, and it seems to work perfectly fine.

It *seems* to work perfectly fine, and in the most extremely simple cases, it might even work. However:

The `View` method needs to iterate through the data that you pass in. In the case of a `DbSet<T>`, this means that the entire database table will be `SELECT`ed **synchronously**. There are tons of posts/etc about the difference between synchronous and asynchronous operations including database calls, so I won't go deeper into the details other than saying: in most cases, synchronous usage of Entity Framework Core must be avoided.
This means that, in order to ensure the asynchronous execution of the query, one of the asynchronous query executors must be used, `ToListAsync` being a common choice, although `ToArrayAsync` would work just as fine for this purpose.

That's the first part. The second part is that, since you are returning a reference to `DbSet<T>`, the data is not in memory yet, so an open connection to the database is required until some point in time when the query is executed. Another problem is that the query might end up being executed *multiple times*, depending on the implementation of whatever takes care of sending the result back to the client.